# Are multiline labels with the tikzlibrary quotes possible?

Tags: tikz-pgf, line-breaking

MWE:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
   graphs,
   graphdrawing,
   positioning,
   quotes,
}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [
    tree layout,
    edge quotes center,
    edges={nodes={fill=white}},
    level distance=30mm,   
] {
    a ->["first line\\second line"] b ->["y"] c ->["z"] d;   }; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

returns

[image]

As you can see the linebreak is ignored. What do I have to do when using the tikzlibrary `quotes` to use linebreaks in edge labels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The additional options for the quote is taken as label options. Hence any linebreaking-option would cause it to have multilines such as `align=...` or `text width=<dimension>`.

With

```
a ->["first line\\second line", align=center] b ->["y"] c ->["z"] d;
```

we get

[image]